# How do create url to django Admin within my user page (HTML)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-urls

I'm new to coding, I'm trying to create URL link in NavBar to redirect my Django Admin exmple:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin'%}"> Admin site </a>
```

However, Django do find; No-Reverse-Match,

It works for other URL links

Things I had to try:

1. Is adding a name in project URL
2. including URL path in my App URL

My project URL code:

```
from Django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin' ),
    path(r'accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path(r'api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'), name='rest_framework'),
    path(r'', include('app.urls')),
```

My App URL code:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views #function views
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, permission_required


from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tank', views.TankViewSet)
router.register(r'room', views.RoomViewSet)
# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'',login_required(views.index), name='index'),
    path (r'test/',views.Test),
    path(r'^Water/',login_required(views.Lquid), name='tank'),
    path(r'^Ambient/',login_required(views.Ambient), name='room'),
    path(r'Rest-api/', include(router.urls)),
   #path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls, name='admin' ), this somthing I had try
    ]
```

Basically, Django makes in a way that works and redirect to the URL link on any page

NAVBAR:
 Admin site

App URL:
path(r'',login_required(views.index), name='index'),

With this two link it will redricet to the page you set.

Apprentice if you cold help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to specify the admin page you want to redirect to when doing a reverse lookup of admin. To get to the admin homepage you will want this reverse lookup

```
reverse('admin:index')
```

So to link to the admin homepage in your nav bar, it should look like this

```py
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'admin:index' %}"> Admin site </a>
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-reverse-urls) on how to reverse lookup admin pages

Comment: Thank you Mikeyj, will check out the document.